# Regex for characters within a boundary

Tags: regex

Consider this string:

> "Count":42,"Hits":75,"Ranges":[5,10,15,20],"Title":"Chart"

I would like a Regex to try and capture the only the commas **','** which occur inside the brackets **[** and **]**. Is this possible?

I can match the entire list by using `\[.*\]` as my regex, but only want the commas.

Comment: So you'll get an array of commas. Can you explain how useful that information is? Wouldn't you be better off with the numbers instead?

Comment: This looks like JSON content to me.  Are you trying to parse JSON using regular expressions?  Don't do that; it's a bad idea.  Use a JSON parser.

Comment: In C#: `Regex.Replace(s, @"\[[^][]+]", m=>m.Value.Replace(",", "")`

Comment: What language or tool are you using? Add it as a tag as it makes a big difference as to the capabilities of the regex engine.

Comment: try this one `,(?=\d+.*\])`

Comment: Originally, I had a need for this regex in order to find and replace all commas which exist only within a boundary. I found another solution eventually, but because I could not find any clues on Stack Overflow on how to make that regex, I figured I would ask the question anyway (without any hard parameters on language, tool, or indeed purpose). The eventual answer would add to the sum of knowledge within Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should match the commas `,` inside square bracket in the given string

```
,(?=\d+.*\])
```

- `,` matches comma
- `(?=\d+.*\])` positive look ahead asserts number and a closing square bracket  exists ahead of `,`

[see demo](https://regex101.com/r/B2RFcE/3)

Comment: Exactly what I was hoping for - an answer and an explanation. Thanks!